# long initial delay followed by "Can't open display" for ssh forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

I am experiencing a strange delay, on the order of a minute, when starting even trivial applications (think: vim) over an X connection tunneled through ssh.

If the application starts (vim), the delay does not persist while using the application, only on startup. Nearly all applications, even simple ones (xterm, xclock, etc.), both exhibit the delay and thereafter abort with "Can't open display: localhost:0.0".

A clue:

```
└─ $ ▶ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
└─ $ ▶ export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

solves the delay problem with vim, but not with the other applications: the delay persists, followed by the eventual abort.

If the solution to this problem is not obvious, suggestions for how to debug what is happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you're sitting in front of a computer, and it's running X. And on that computer you're running ssh to connect to a remote system with X forwarding. And on the remote system DISPLAY is set to "localhost:10.0"? And X apps hang when you try to run them? And setting it to localhost:0.0 fixes vim but nothing else? Is this all correct? Are you sure that vim is using X when you set DISPLAY to localhost:0.0? What is DISPLAY set to on the local system (the one you're running ssh on)?

Comment: All of that is correct- I believe that vim is using X over ssh is that vim only starts with the delay when using X tunneling. When not tunneling (i.e., ssh vs ssh -X), vim starts immediately. DISPLAY on my local system is set to `:1`.